# UIAppearanceCustomizableClassInfo tableView:numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I have a view controller containing table view. In particular scenario I am re - initiating the view controller. In that case I am getting this error.

UItabelViewWrapperView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection

Note: My code is perfectly runing on ios 7. It keeps getting crash in ios 8.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. On my end, the problem was appearing when the view controller was popping to its root, navigating to the new views controller that I wanter and finally go back to the very first view controller (that was on another tab). So the solution for me was to remove the popToRootViewController method. That worked for me. I don't know your code in detail so I can't provide you a better solution or opinions.

I hope that helps.

n.b.: I am doing the navigation from AppDelegate.